# SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker-compose

i'm trying to implement docker in my rails api but I keep getting this error
`PG::ConnectionBad: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above`.
I've try all the solutions I've found on the internet, even in another questions here, but none of them works. anybody knows the solution to this?

Comment: Yes. The solution is what all the answers will tell you: upgrade the PostgreSQL client software in the container that gets the error. I know containers are all about *not* upgrading anything, but asking again won't change the truth.

Answer (score 0):

You need the update de image you are using in your container. I've had the same problem for running [flywaydb](https://hub.docker.com/r/boxfuse/flyway).
I updated the [latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/flyway/flyway) image version and solve this problem.